# String as a json value over network transmission getting cut in between

Tags: android, json, string

We are posting some details to the server using android application. The posted value will be the JSON String. In Some cases the String value getting cut in between when reaching server. Is it possible when packets getting lost in server end? This String will be added in the Json Value and being sent to the server.
For Example correct JSON String format is

```
"3032320162225141|~|2032320162225141|~||~|0|~|47965|~|09:00:00|~|First call|~|134,322|~|0.0|~|0.0|~|2016-03-23 09:00:00|~|2016-03-23 22:25:14|~|347|~|325|~|0|~|0|~|0|~~~|"
```

and in Some Cases we are receiving it like

```
"3032320162225141|~|2032320162225141|~||~|0|~|47965|~|09:00:00|~|First call|~|134,322|~|0.0|~|0.0|09 09:00:00|~|2016-03-23 22:25:14|~~~|"
```

As you are seeing some delimiters are merged and in some places entire values are missing. This is happening very rarely and particularly in some server alone. Please give some ideas of what could be the reason behind this?

This is the String Builder code:

```
public String build_Customer(String Table,
        String ColumnstoUpload, String PrimaryColumn) {

    String CustomerStr = new String();
    Table_CustomerStr = "\"";

    int primaryKeyIndex = 0;

    String[] columns = ColumnstoUpload.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        if (PrimaryColumn.toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase(
                columns[i].toLowerCase())) {
            primaryKeyIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.select("Query for the Records");
    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
                String s = "";
                if (c.getString(i) == null || c.getString(i).equals("null"))                      {
                    s = "";
                } else {
                    s = c.getString(i);
                }
                Table_CustomerStr = Table_CustomerStr  + s
                        + "|~|"; // add Column Delimiter
                if (i == primaryKeyIndex) {
                    //Some Operation for Primary Key
                }
            }
            Table_CustomerStr = Table_CustomerStr.substring(
                    0, Table_CustomerStr.lastIndexOf("|~|"));
            Table_CustomerStr = Table_CustomerStr + "|~~~|"; //add Row Delimiter
        }
        c.moveToFirst();
    } else {
        c.close();
        db.close();
        return "\"\"";
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    Table_CustomerStr = Table_CustomerStr .substring(0,
            Table_CustomerStr .lastIndexOf("|~~~|"));
    Table_CustomerStr = Table_CustomerStr + "\"";
    return Table_CustomerStr;
}
```

Is there anything above to doubt which can cause the issue in the String? This is specifically happening in the rare case scenerio.

Comment: This is working correctly when we are checking it in local environment. But in client end it is happening. Tested Both in GPRS and WIFI connections and found working correctly.

Comment: JSON? That doesn't look anything like json - http://www.json.org/

Comment: This String will be added as a value in JSON.  Eg): {"authCode":"XXX","reqCode":"Customer","positionId":"35","userId":"37","DeviceNo":"1563457894","VersionNo":"1.1.63","uploadData":{"Table_Customer":"3032320162225141|~|2032320162225141|~||~|0|~|47965|~|09:00:00|~|First call|~|134,322|~|0.0|~|0.0|~|2016-03-23 09:00:00|~|2016-03-23 22:25:14|~|347|~|325|~|0|~|0|~|0|~~~|"}}

Comment: I too feel like JSON is nothing to do with this issue. But your inputs are needed for this.

Comment: Would it not make sense to create a json object for the 'uploadData'? That would be easier to debug and a lot more structured for both the client and server.

Comment: i doubt such thing may happen, losing part of the data while being transmitted, however there is a possibility that the code -sometimes- could generate invalid (short) data for any reason (empty db, data in db not as expected ... etc)

Comment: because this is handled on either protocol level or other lower levels (network layer) such thing will cause a failure for the request, but not receiving part of data (at least i am thinking about the header `content-length` if it does not match, then ... !!! talking packets this is a much lower level, i am sure it's handled in a way that the request will be failed completely